How do I combine rows from different tables in one view?
My database stores events from C++ structs of report information. All structs have common fields (id, timestamp) but also unique ones (application.name, user.name). I need data for one component from tables with different columns.
Table1:



eventId
timestamp
application.name
…




1
1224545
ui.exe
…


…
…
…
…



Table2:



eventId
timestamp
user.name
…




1
2133333
TestUser1
…


…
…
…
…



I want to use CREATE VIEW to get:



eventId
timestamp
application.name
user.name
…




1
1224545
ui.exe
{null}
…


1
2133333
{null}
TestUser1
…


…
…
…
…
…



How can I do this?

You could use the UNION operator:
CREATE VIEW viewname AS

SELECT eventid, timestamp, "application.name", NULL AS 'user.name'
FROM table1

UNION ALL

SELECT eventid, timestamp, NULL AS 'application.name', "user.name"
FROM table2


thank you, I haven't known that I can create not existing columns in a table
